# How can we contact or engage the moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Presumably one of the roles of moderators is to correct users that are performing clearly erroneous reviews.  I thought the two users who [rejected this edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/131654) could probably use some guidance, which AFAIK can only be provided by mods.

So I tried to find some means of contacting the moderators.  There was no chat room for ELU moderation (although [I created one for them they might consider using](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26515/english-mods)).  No moderators were present in the [regular ELU chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage).  So I pinged them *all*.  [30 hours later Kit Z. Fox responded](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23191841#23191841) with an explanation of what a rejection is.  I said I didn't think the rejections were warranted.  [17 hours later](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23205608#23205608) Kit replied, "I don't have an opinion on it."

So is this just a more laissez-faire site than the typical Stack Exchange?  Or am I missing some better means of engaging the moderators here?

Comment: Hmm. Pinging in Chat **is** the way get moderators' attention if a flag is not appropriate (as in this case). But I didn't get that ping. However, it is the case that once an edit is rejected, there's nothing which can be done to reinstate it.

Comment: The best time to find active moderators in ELU chat is in the mornings U.S. time. You will nearly never find one active there this late at night.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - A Moderator can send a moderator message to at least let them know what they did was erroneous and clarify the standards of review.

Comment: @feetwet - This is a very busy site, busier than any of the others I'm on (I'm *not* on SO), but I've never had a problem getting a mod's attention within a few hours. It's true that they are easier to catch starting around 4-5 am EST. However, truthfully, I wouldn't bother them over something like this (even though I agree with you that it was a good and valid edit.) For this, 30 hours seems about right, since there's little they can do about it anyway. Also, meta has had a number of posts on bad editing.

Comment: @medica  I have flags that have been pending for weeks on end. Those flags are the trickier ones to deal with. It's like the mods deliberately "ignore" them, but if I flag an offensive rude comment, or a post that does not answer the OP, that gets handled very quickly. I imagine, that before mods go into action, so to speak, they want to see more than one flag.

Comment: saying that, I wouldn't want a mod breathing down my neck every time I made an incorrect or clumsy edit. The rationale behind the non approval was that the edit was superficial, I disagree, but that's my opinion. Some will agree with your suggested edit and others will consider whether the post deserves bumping to the front. ICYDK, every time a post is edited, it gets bumped to the top of the "active page". Some users find even bumping ONE old question, tiresome. Again there are meta posts that discuss this aspect.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'm not talking about flags at all. I'm talking about pinging mods, and how long it takes them to answer to pings. If I time it correctly, most of the time I get a mod immediately. That was what the OP asked about. And, as I said, I wouldn't bother a mod for the reason the OP cites.

Comment: @medica  There are mods from Europe as well as American, there shouldn't be any need to to calculate when best to "ping" them. And flags are handled by mods, not by anyone else, it is a less direct way of communicating with them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't understand the point you're trying to make. I relayed my experience. If you agree with feetwet, then agree with her. Why you're addressing comments to me about things I haven't even brought up is unclear to me. I *have* noticed that the best time to get a mod is in the wee hours, probably (initially, anyway) because of new mod energy. "You should not be able to get a mod other times" is not an opinion I expressed. Again, I've said nothing about flags. A long answer to an issue I never raised puzzles me.